# Suspiciously high frequencies of certain counts with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am working with Google Analytics data und during the analysis I saw that I have wierd distribution of visits. For instance, the minimum visits for a page is 89, wich also has the highes freq count in my dataset. Then I have 177 visits for a page with the second highest freq count. I find this pattern every month...

Does anyone know anything about that?

Comment: Pages do not have visits (visits are a session level metric), pages have pageviews (which are a hit level metric).  Plus questions on the reporting interface are off-topic and should rather go to webmasters.stackexchange.com.

Comment: of course you are right. sorry for the mix up. And you are probably right about the rest too, eventhough I work with the api. thx

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might have some combination of repeated trackers, heavy spam or over-impactful bot traffic.

Repeated trackers an be identified using Realtime reporting: if you click onto the Page Views tag, does each page load trigger only one page view?

Spam can often be identified using the Hostname. Run a custom report looking at Hostnames, and you can see if it's coming from freebuttons.xyz or some equally scummy location.

Finally, bot traffic can be filtered out using an option in the view settings: try setting up a duplicate View with this setting on, and see how different the volumes are.